# FMDB type Local db library for Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am looking for a library in Android which handles local db in android like FMDB in ios.
Something which takes care of all the heavy duty work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **SugarORM**.
It is intended to simplify the interaction with SQLite database in Android.

**Benefits**

It eliminates writing SQL queries to interact with SQLite db.

It takes care of creating your database.

It manages object relationships too.

It provides you with clear and simple APIs for db operations

**Why it was made**  ->  **had following characteristics :**

Fairly large and complex data model.

Primary work was to save/retrieve and iterate over the business objects.

Lot of boiler plate code for the db operations.

We wanted to write our business logic in less technical and more business fashion.

**It Provides**

1) database creation

2)simple APIs to manipulate your business objects

refer these links, you will get the idea about how to use it and implement in project

http://satyan.github.io/sugar/

http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html